# Evaluate function giving type mismatch VBA

Tags: vba, function, mismatch, evaluate

is anyone able to help on the below please? I'm sure it's something to do with the "s but i just can't seem to get the right combination. I Keep getting type mismatch error.

JOBKEY = Evaluate("=Vlookup(FORM!A7,LISTS!A:B,2,0)") & amendno

Thanks!

Comment: What is the result of the VLOOKUP function itself? What happen if there is no match?

Comment: Hi, it looks up using a users' selection from a drop down list so will always find a relevant value and won't error out from that part. But i seem to either get a type mismatch or error 2024 meaning the formula is returning an error